# How to change the color of selected text?

Tags: html, css

Please left-click and drag over this text (mark it). The color you are seeing is blue, I would like to change that color to a dark green using Javascript or HTML/CSS?

Comment: When you hover, or when you right click?

Comment: **I do not see blue.** Please repeat after me: **users can change the highlight/selection color used on their computer**. And they often choose to do so. Please respect their choice; they probably have a good reason for doing so. There is absolutely no reason you should be changing that with CSS, Javascript, or anything else.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Browser support is limited.

```
::selection {
        background: #ffb7b7; /* Safari */
        }
::-moz-selection {
        background: #ffb7b7; /* Firefox */
}
```

[Example](http://css-tricks.com/examples/DifferentSelectionColors/).

[Further Reading](http://css-tricks.com/overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/).

Answer (score 2):

http://snipplr.com/view/4285/change-color-of-selected-text/

Its CSS3 and only Safari and Firefox are supporting this, and both in slightly different ways