# Change text colour when text is selected in mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, css, select, mobile-safari

Is there any way to change the colour of the selected text in mobile Safari, either with CSS or JavaScript?

I'm looking at a system where spoilers are rendered in white on white to prevent people reading them unless they actively select the text.

Not surprisingly, this doesn't work in iPhones. Is there a way around this?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101291/how-to-change-the-color-of-selected-text) shows that it can be done with regular Safari, but the code doesn't work on Mobile.

Comment: does ::selection {} fail at both color and background-color?   Man, I've got to get one of these to test on.

Comment: Yes, it does. Happy to test anything you come up with!